# AdMob adView not reacting to key press

Tags: android, view, focus, admob, onkeypress

I want to change way that focus from adMob goes to other controls in my code.
For now it behaves that when I press right arrow key, focus goes to another control.

I want it to do the same with down arrow.
I've tried adding OnKeyListener and setNextFocusDownId without any results.

Besides sample code from adMob I don't have any changes, all is displaying OK on top of application window.

Target is android 2.1 on android 2.2 it works out of the box.